# Firebug Lite on Chrome - how to log to console with PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, console, firebug, firebug-lite

I installed the extension Firebug Lite in Chrome.
In Firefox I use FirePHP to log messages in the console, but I can't get it to work in Chrome.

I also installed ChromePHP. With this I can log messages to the built-in Developer Tools for Chrome, but I wish to log to Firebug Lite !

Is this even possible to send a message to the console in Firebug Lite from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in the normal Firebug either (I'm talking about Firefox). You have to use FirePHP for that purpose. So you can't do that in Firebug Lite, and I don;t think that there is any extension similar to FirePHP for Chrome (that would interact with Firebug Lite). For PHP &Ajax debugging I am using PHP Console extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef?hl=en-US.

**UPDATE**
I found a better solution, and that is: https://github.com/andrewn/firephp-chrome. The best part about it is that it allows the Chrome console to display FirePHP messages. There are some bugs, but I'm quite satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to echo it out to javascript.

```
function ConsoleLog($message)
{
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $message. '")</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple/lightweight solution you can also try ChromePHP:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd

Getting started guide available at:

http://www.chromephp.com